# jQuery html function not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this jQuery snippet:

```
$('#wrapper').html('<img src="/loading.gif">');
    var formdata = $("#validateuserform").serialize();
        $.post("/userformdata.php",formdata,function(html){
            if(html){
                $("#wrapper").html('Mail sent!');
                $('#validateuserform').clearForm();
            }
        });
```

That does not quite work. What is supposed to happen, is for the wrapper's html to change to "Mail sent!", and the form to be cleared after clicking a button.

But, it just spins and spins, nothing happens, and I can't figure out what's wrong.

---

Figured it out.

I deleted: echo "yes";

from userformdata.php

... Added it back, and it worked. Thanks for all the replies and engagement - will for sure pay it back to the community :)

Comment: Just wondering, the `'enter code here'` is written properly?

Comment: I assume server-side code is working properly...

Comment: @Aister that was an error on my part, when I tried to fit the code inside the code tag - it is removed now :)

Comment: @atas That's what I'm currently trying to figure out now, as I can't find anything wrong with the code - which is why I posted it here just to have a second set of eyes on it ;)

Comment: What's in validateuserform?

Comment: Did you check if you enter the `if(html)` part? use `console.log('outside/inside')` to see. You can also use a tool like Fiddler to see the server's response.

Comment: Please show your server side code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use some sort of debugger (Firebug or Chromedebugger) to check if you got an error with your POST, and debug from there since it seems that it never got to the section where it changes #wrapper's html.

Comment: Alright, post appears to be fine: "200 OK  3,05s"
... But the "HTML" tab is empty!

Comment: Hmm, if you are using a debugger, you could try and put a breakpoint in your js file, so you could step through your javascript and check why it isn't firing